# how can I move my Qt project to another PC

Tags: export, project, package, qt-creator

I am working on a Qt GUI project in a PC with Qt Creator. I want to shift this project to a new PC installed with Qt Creator. Can I know how can I create a single package of my current qt project work to export to another PC.

I tried to copy just the whole project folder but it din't work. The resource files din't came and I am getting a lot of compilation errors.

Answer (score 10):

There is no such option to export/import a project in QtCreator, however...

You can copy a project folder of your application on new machine if you have identical configuration:

- QtCreator and Qt library are installed in the same path as on old machine.
- Project folder is copied into the same path on other machine.

The reason is simple: [Application.pro.user file contains absolute paths.](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-7614)

On the other hand, you can copy your folder into any new path. Delete Application.pro.user file. And open Application.pro in QtCreator - you will create new local project. QtCreator will ask you what Qt version you want to use.

If you have a problem with your resource files, ensure that you do not use absolute paths.
Open resources.qrc file in text editor and see what paths you have there.